# Running a binary identified as an ARM excutable by binwalk --disasm

Tags: binary-analysis, firmware, arm

I have a Philips 10FF2 picture frame I'm trying to reverse engineer. In the firmware download from the Philips website (http://download.p4c.philips.com/files/1/10ff2cme_00/10ff2cme_00_fus_aen.zip) I can find a file called `UBLDM350.bin` which when analyzed with `binwalk --disasm` gives me:

```
DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0             0x0             ARM executable code, 32-bit, little endian, at least 984 valid instructions
```

My question is how do I get more information on this file? I tried running it with qemu-arm but that fails:

```
walterheck@walter-toshiba:~/projects/pictureframe/PHILIPS.10FF2M$ qemu-arm ./UBLDM350.BIN 
Error while loading ./UBLDM350.BIN: Permission denied
```

Running `strings` on it gives me garbage and only a few readable things:

```
(null)
0123456789abcdef0123456789ABCDEF
...fail(%d)
NANDReadPage error(%d)
Error block(%d)
Magic switch failure(0x%X)
Bad block found(block=%d)
Move done.
Start boot from NAND
Ver = %s
UBLN1.05
```

I'm looking for help on what to try next.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Obstacles

One of the difficulties associated with analyzing firmware is that firmware binaries do not usually have a standard format and do not segregate code and data in a standard manner like ELF or PE binaries do. The absence of clearly identifiable partitions within firmware binaries that allow for fast and accurate identification and differentiation between code and data is problematic for disassembly, since a disassembler such as [Capstone](https://github.com/aquynh/capstone) (which is used to identify  to identify the CPU architecture by `binwalk` when the `--disasm` argument is used) or [Radare2](https://github.com/radare/radare2) will disassemble data (such as ASCII strings) as opcodes and operands.

It appears that this is the case with `UBLDM350.BIN`. If `binwalk -A` is executed, we see that ARM code is detected fairly uniformly from offset 0x130 to offset 0x4224, a range of 16628 bytes:

```
$ binwalk -A UBLDM350.BIN

DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
304           0x130           ARM instructions, function prologue
792           0x318           ARM instructions, function prologue
1396          0x574           ARM instructions, function prologue
8008          0x1F48          ARM instructions, function prologue
9380          0x24A4          ARM instructions, function prologue
9880          0x2698          ARM instructions, function prologue
9908          0x26B4          ARM instructions, function prologue
10024         0x2728          ARM instructions, function prologue
10320         0x2850          ARM instructions, function prologue
13036         0x32EC          ARM instructions, function prologue
13080         0x3318          ARM instructions, function prologue
13196         0x338C          ARM instructions, function prologue
13548         0x34EC          ARM instructions, function prologue
15912         0x3E28          ARM instructions, function prologue
16872         0x41E8          ARM instructions, function prologue
16932         0x4224          ARM instructions, function prologue
```

However, when `binwalk --disasm --verbose` is run to print the disassembled instructions, the memory address range of the disassembled code is much less than this (`0x00` to `0xF5C` = 3932 bytes):

```
$ binwalk --disasm --verbose UBLDM350.BIN

Scan Time:     2017-05-07 10:56:43
Target File:   /home/c/firmware/Philips/10FF2cme_pictureframe/PHILIPS.10FF2M/UBLDM350/UBLDM350.BIN
MD5 Checksum:  15b2dac3ce98d3308d9c6cf47e74eba7

DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0             0x0             ARM executable code, 32-bit, little endian, at least 984 valid instructions
0             0x0             ldr r0, [pc, #0x124]
4             0x4             mcr p15, #0, r0, c9, c1, #0
8             0x8             mov r0, r0
12            0xC             mrs r0, apsr
16            0x10            bic r0, r0, #0x1f
20            0x14            orr r0, r0, #0x11
24            0x18            msr cpsr_fc, r0
28            0x1C            ldr sp, [pc, #0xf4]
32            0x20            ldr r0, [pc, #0xf4]
36            0x24            add sp, sp, r0
40            0x28            mrs r0, apsr

< snip >

3888          0xF30           lsl ip, ip, #0x16
3892          0xF34           lsr ip, ip, #0x16
3896          0xF38           strh ip, [sp, #0x16]
3900          0xF3C           ldrh ip, [sp, #0x14]
3904          0xF40           ldr r0, [sp, #4]
3908          0xF44           ldrb r1, [ip, r0]
3912          0xF48           ldrb r2, [sp, #0x16]
3916          0xF4C           eor r1, r2, r1
3920          0xF50           strb r1, [ip, r0]
3924          0xF54           mov r0, #0
3928          0xF58           add sp, sp, #0x1c
3932          0xF5C           bx lr
```

Why is this? A broken instruction causes Capstone to cease disassembly following offset `0xF5C`:

> By default, Capstone stops disassembling when it encounters a broken instruction. Most of the time, the reason is that this is data mixed inside the input, and it is understandable that Capstone does not understand this "weird" code.
>
> Typically, you are recommended to dertermine yourself where the next code is, and then continue disassembling from that place.<sup>[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVsEw.png)](http://www.capstone-engine.org/skipdata.html)</sup>

[image: invalid instructions at offset 0xf60]

Above we see that there are indeed invalid instructions following the instruction at offset `0xF5C`.

Some of the following data is disassembled as code:

```
00001ba0  bf f9 0a 1c 02 e0 d3 17  02 f0 92 fc 19 1c 10 1c  |................|
00001bb0  70 bc 04 bc 10 47 c0 46  30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37  |p....G.F01234567|
00001bc0  38 39 61 62 63 64 65 66  30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37  |89abcdef01234567|
00001bd0  38 39 41 42 43 44 45 46  00 00 00 00 04 d0 4d e2  |89ABCDEF......M.|
00001be0  00 c0 a0 e3 00 c0 8d e5  00 c0 9d e5 2a 00 5c e3  |............*.\.|
```

[image: data disassembled as code]

Direct execution of the binary likely fails due to the fact that there is no header that provides the kernel program loader the information required to create a process image in memory, such as the entry point and binary layout information.

#### Options

**1. Unicorn**

An option for further investigation could be using the [Unicorn engine](https://github.com/unicorn-engine/unicorn) to dynamically analyze successfully disassembled code. See this Q&A for more information:

[Unicorn and QEMU: Example use cases to understand the differences](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/12540/unicorn-and-qemu-example-use-cases-to-understand-the-differences)

**2. Device processor identification**

If you have direct access to the hardware, it may prove useful to identify the exact processor/microcontroller, since this will allow you to locate the technical reference manual and datasheet, which will describe in detail the memory layout and instruction set architecture of the device. Knowledge of memory layout will aid in the analysis of the firmware binary.

**3. Hex dump analysis**

Analysis of a hex dump may allow you to manually identify non-code portions of the firmware. Portions with code only can be sliced out and disassembled by Capstone, r2, or some other disassembler.

**4. Visualization**

Visualization of the firmware binary using `binwalk -E` can give an insight into the overall structure of the binary. An entropy plot allows for fast identification of compressed or regions of contiguous null bytes. [binvis.io](http://binvis.io/#/) is a useful source for binary visualization as well.

See also:

[Approach to extract useful information from binary file](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/15006/approach-to-extract-useful-information-from-binary-file/15025#15025)

---

<sub>1. [SKIPDATA mode](http://www.capstone-engine.org/skipdata.html)</sub>

Comment: Took me a while to get back to this project. I'm fiddling around with some of your suggestions now. As for option 2: I do indeed have access to the hardware itself. The central chip seems to be a DMSoc from TI identified by TMS320DM350ZWK. This seems to have been released later as TMS320DM355, of which a datasheet is here: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tms320dm355.pdf.

Comment: @WalterHeck according to the data sheet, the device uses an [ARM926EJ-S processor](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0198e/Cacheeja.html)

Answer (score 4):

To add to SYS_V's good answer, this 'weird' mixing of code and data is actually very common with ARM code.

ARM instructions are fixed sizes (4 bytes on ARM, 2 bytes for THUMB) and have insufficient space to encode an 32 bit immediate value.  Instead, ARM compilers usually do two things -

1. they place 32 bit immediate constants straight after the instructions for the function in which the constants are needed, and
2. they use PC-relative load instructions in the function to put these constants into registers.

In SYS_V's disassembly, the instructions at addresses `0x00000F08` and `0x00000F28` are both PC relative loads. (Though the disassembler is being helpful here and displaying the calculated addresses `0x00000FF8` and `0x00000FFC` rather than showing `[PC,offset]`.)

The disassembler is further being helpful and annotating the disassembly in red at the side showing the values of the immediate constants that will be loaded.  In this case the values loaded are `0x01E100D4` and `0x01E100DC` respectively.

It's usual to see the immediate constants stored after the function in order of the addresses of the functions that access them.  So, in this case, the function ends with the instruction at `0x00000F5C` and the immediate constants would appear to span the address range `0x00000F60` to `0x00000FFF` and I would usually expect the following function to begin at address `0x00001000`.

Knowing this it would be possible for a disassembler to identify this pattern and automatically skip the associated data.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you have a raw firmware file and not a user-mode executable. `qemu-arm` only supports user-mode ARM Linux ELF executables. You could in theory try the full-system emulator (`qemu-system-arm`), but don't expect it to work unless QEMU explicitly supports the underlying hardware. It may be also possible to use the QEMU-based [Unicorn emulator](http://www.unicorn-engine.org/) which is somewhat more flexible but you would need to write some code to load your file and start emulation; there's no convenient ready to use program.